# How do I get the switch on the centre

Tags: java, android

I added a switch to my activity and dragged it into the centre. When I launch my app the switch is on the left corner. I can't seem to get it work. Please look at the code and the picture. Thank you. I also have this code on the switch:

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="172dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="242dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the picture?

Comment: what is the parent layout ?

Comment: constrait layout

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the gravity of parent layout:
 android:gravity="center".

Comment: Didn't do anything at all

Comment: This works for linear layout as parent. If You are using it in Relative layout, please add in you switch:
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 for center of screen or

android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
For horizontally centre and

android:layout_centerVertical="true"
For vertically centre. Make sure your parent's width and height is match parent.

Answer (score 0):

#### If parent layout is Linear layout :

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="172dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="242dp" />

// just added android:layout_gravity="center"
```

### In case of Relative layout

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="172dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="242dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ConstraintLayout, by dragging the layout the tools:absolute properties are updated and those are used only on AndroidStudio EDITOR

The real position are based on app:constraint tags.

If you are not familiar with LayoutManagers I think you should start with a easier one such FrameLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout as root of your view.

All mentioned does support the android:layout_gravity="center" on childrem or android:gravity="true" on parent for all childrem.